# How do I get Charles Proxy to Accept traffic for sites that have invalid certs?

Tags: iphone, ssl, proxy, charles-proxy, sslhandshakeexception

I'm trying to test some changes from my iPhone for a website that I have running on a VM (which I access from my Macbook).  The website on the VM is HTTPS only, but the cert is invalid because it's a development machine.  My Macbook has a host file entry to the VM, so when I'm testing via the browser all I have to do is accept the invalid cert.  I'm using Charles proxy on the Macbook, and connect my Phone just fine - the only issue is I can't access the site that has the invalid cert:

```
SSLHandshake: Received fatal alert: certificate_unknown
```

Other sites I try to access via the iPhone that are HTTPS work fine. Is there a way to install or accept an invalid cert into the Charles Proxy itself?

Comment: Have you tried install the website certificate on Macbook operating system?